# Non-exhaustive patterns in my function that isn't using patterns?

Tags: haskell

I have the following function:

```
union :: (Eq a) => Set1 a -> Set1 a -> Set1 a
union (MakeSet (x:xs)) (MakeSet (y:ys)) = if (member (MakeSet (y:ys)) x) && (not (isEmpty (MakeSet (x:xs)))) 
                    then union (MakeSet xs) (MakeSet (y:ys)) 
                        else if (not (member (MakeSet (y:ys)) x)) && (not (isEmpty (MakeSet (x:xs)))) 
                            then union (MakeSet xs) (insert x (MakeSet (y:ys))) 
                                else MakeSet (y:ys)
```

It compiles, but when I execute it with parameters I get that the function has non-exhaustive patterns.

First of all, why does it think I am using patterns? I'm only using conditional statements, and I have an else statement which should catch everything not caught by the if then and else if then statements. Can someone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: What about the pattern `x:xs`?

Comment: `union (MakeSet (x:xs)) (MakeSet (y:ys))` what do you think this is

Comment: I just fixed it by treating it as a pattern and adding a case where the first parameter is empty, so I guess it must be a pattern. Are you saying x:xs is by definition a pattern?

Comment: @Alex Patterns are made up of literals, variables, and constructors.  Any constructor can be used in a pattern, and it just so happens that any operator that begins with `:` is a constructor as well as per the Haskell standard.  The operator `:` is the list cons constructor, it prepends and element on front of a list, so the pattern `x:xs` matches a list with at least one element, with `x` being the first element and `xs` being the rest of the list and can be empty.

Comment: It needs to be said that both `MakeSet` and `:` are pattern matching. In your case it looks like `MakeSet` matching can't fail, but matching the list `x:xs` can fail - this statement assumes the list can be split into head and tail, so the list isn't empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(MakeSet (x:xs))` is a pattern, and it is not exhaustive: it doesn't match `MakeSet []`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
union (MakeSet (x:xs)) (MakeSet (y:ys)) = ...
```

means the same thing as

```
union = \a b -> case (a, b) of
  (MakeSet (x : xs), MakeSet (y : ys)) -> ...
```

so yes, your code is already using pattern matching. See [translation for function bindings](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-850004.4.3.1) in the [Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/).

The problem is (as noted in amalloy's answer) that you are matching on `MakeSet (... : ...)` but not on `MakeSet []`, so you're missing some case. To fix this, add more equations to match on the missing cases.